# FastCV build errors

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

"size_t" could not be resolved, and "field corners could not be resolved".

This is the code that came with the sample.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Also, does anyone have any up-to-date, actually working instructions on how to install fastCV? I would be most appreciative. The instructions given by Qualcomm are simply unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a NDK.
It can be downloaded here : http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing

On eclipse windows > Preference > Android >NDK browser to your NDK derectory.
Project clean.